# Number of ways to choose 2 subsets with condition

Tags: combinatorics

Given set $X \subseteq \mathbb Z$, $|X|=n$, how many ways are there to choose a subset of size $k$ and a subset of size $l$, such that the largest element in the $k$-sized set is smaller than the smallest element in the $l$-sized set. $k$ and $l$ are fixed, and $k+l \le n$

Have no idea how to approach this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution boils down to counting the number of subsets of size $k+l$ of a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ of size $n$.  For each such choice, the $k$ smallest elements make up the first subset, while the remaining $l$ elements form the second subset.  That number is $\binom{n}{k+l}$.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting confused and didn't catch that I need to choose the $k$ smallest elements and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a subset $A$ of size $k+l$. Let its smallest $k$ elements form
a set $B$ and its largest $l$ elements form a set $C$. How many ways
are there to pick $k+l$ elements from $X$?